# GCM how many 3rd party servers Can Use a single server key?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Friends, I have a doubt on GCM technology that, how may 3rd party server can use a single server key? and can two different server send messages to 1000 mobiles ( totally 2000 device token ) at a time through GCM server?
I hope I will get clarified on this soon.

Thanks in advance,
Umarajeshwaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of servers that can use the same key. Any request to GCM can have up to 1000 registration ids, so if you have multiple servers sending multiple requests,  you can send more than 1000 ids at the same time.